# mysql sort by distance between dates

Tags: mysql

i have the following issue, i have a table with *classes*, the date they were published and the date they were updated. I need to get the *classes* that were updated closer to certain date, in past or future. So im trying to do something like:

`select * from mytable sort by (difference_between_dates)`

the **difference_between_dates** would be the time between the **update_date** and the **date im looking for**. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`DATEDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(update_date, "2013-04-10")
```

Perhaps wrap it in an [`ABS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) if future vs past doesn't matter.